# how to apply a regex to a string in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, regex

I'm trying to use jquery to select the contents of a certain XML node:

```
var entry_text = $('entry_text').text();
```

and apply a regular expression to it, sort of like this one:

```
\<entry_text\>(?<url>.*?/&gt;)(?<text>.*?)\</entry_text\>
```

So that if this is the XML node entry_text:

```
<entry_text>&lt;img src=&quot;http://site.com/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;431&quot; height=&quot;480&quot; /&gt;
    Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</entry_text>
```

I'll get something like this:

```
<entry_text>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</entry_text>
<entry_image><img src="http://site.com/image.jpg" width="431" height="480"/>
```

Only I'm not sure what the right regex is, or how to apply it to my string. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this data you've acquired through an XmlHttpRequest? If so, why not use JSON?

Comment: this is an XML file I've dumped from a database which I'm trying to clean up so I can import the data into a new CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check these useful pages:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

and this is also a great plugin for regx matching in jquery:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/regular-expression

Let me know if this helped you, thanks.